# Detection of memory leak in a command line program c++ in Xcode 10

Tags: c++, xcode, debugging, memory-leaks, heap-memory

I'm trying to understand c++, but i had some compatibility problems between valgrind and mac os mojave so i decide to use xcode.
First of all my doubt was, how can i detect
memory leaks(invoke a new without a delete) with a very simple command line program?
I have read that someone use Instruments panel so i start with it but in the call tree nothing appears.
I specify that my c++ program is too short but i think it isn't a problem.
Are there some flags to set up in build schemes? 
is there another way to do that?
Does anyone use xcode? please help me!

Comment: Do you "Run"  your program or do you "Profile" it?

Comment: I try both, when i profile it i saw that something should appears in call tree but i have only <allocated prior to attach>. Instead when i run i don't understand which are my allocated objects that haven't been freed ( previous memory graph access)